# Having a heading on one side and a list on another

Tags: html, css, list, inline

So I have my `h1` and `h3` set to the left of my screen but inline with them, on the right, I would like my list to be but at the moment it is underneath the `h` elements.

```css
header h1, h3 {
    margin-top: 60px;
    margin-bottom: 0%;
    margin-left: 100px;
}

header h3 {
    margin-top: 0%;
}

header li {
    display: inline;
    list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <h1>NAME</h1>
    <h3>ASPIRING WEB DEVELOPER</h3>
    <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>Projects</li>
        <li>About Me</li>
        <li>Contact info</li>
    </ul>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```css
header h1, h3 {
    margin-top: 60px;
    margin-bottom: 0%;
    margin-left: 100px;
}

header h3 {
    margin-top: 0%;
}

header li {
    display: inline;
    list-style: none;
}
header {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <div>
      <h1>NAME</h1>
      <h3>ASPIRING WEB DEVELOPER</h3>
    </div>
    <div>
      <ul>
          <li>Home</li>
          <li>Projects</li>
          <li>About Me</li>
          <li>Contact info</li>
      </ul>
    </div
</header>
```